# Starting Where Query Left Off in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, groovy

I have this code in groovy, and I am using PostgreSQL to access the database server.

If I execute this query, it will get logs from the starting point until the end. **However, logs are continuously being added every week, is there a possible way to add into the code where I can start where I left off when the code runs again?**

```
def logs = new Logs()
      String query = "SELECT * from auditLog where created < (CURRENT_DATE)::date order by id ASC"
      PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)        
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()
```

For example:
1st run: Logs from December 1 - December 20(not fixed)
2nd run: Logs from December 21 - December 31(not fixed)
3rd run: Logs from January 1 - January 15(not fixed)
and so on....

Important thing is to be able to start where I left off, which in this case is December 21

It should by Dynamic

Comment: Just track when you last ran it.

Comment: @DaveNewton any tips in terms of how to code it? Really new to this

Comment: Save the date somewhere. Read it back in, use that as a query param.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * 
from    auditLog 
where   '2015-12-21' < created < current_date
```

Since `current_date` is already a `date`, you don't have to cast it.  Note that `created < current_date` will get you rows until the start of today.

Comment: the dates are only an example. Is there a way for it to by dynamic?

Comment: You could store the last query date somewhere. Perhaps a database table or a configuration file. Then you can pass it as a parameter to your query instead of a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply mark the log entries as read (add some status flag) and update each time you read

```
UPDATE auditLog set read = true where id in (<selected ids>)
```

NOTICE: when updating use ids, not "UPDATE where date > ..." to avoid a case where entries have been added while you're reading..

Comment: where will I put the UPDATE auditLog set read = true where id in (<selected ids>) in terms of my code above?